# Image Texture Help

Tags: texturing

I click on my object, then I select the materials tab (small red sphere). Everything is great except when I go into the Node editor (with "Use nodes" turned on) I can't add an Image Texture. In fact the "Texture" group isn't even in the Add menu.

Any thoughts? I'm sure it's a setting.

Normally I open "diffuse" and click the plus sign next to the default white color and then choose "image texture". But the color has no plus sign next to it.

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the entire window? It'll be easier for us to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The materials display for cycles changes dynamically based on what nodes are used. the plus sign is used to show/hide options of a node, it isn't visible unless there are options to hide. When a diffuse shader is shown by itself all of it's options are visible and not collapsible. If a diffuse shader is shown as input to a mix shader then a plus sign will be displayed to show it's options.

[image] [image]

To add an Image texture as input to a colour input of a node you click on the little dot to the left of the colour swatch to get the menu with Image Texture.

[image]

As for the options available in the add node menu of the node editor, check that you are using the right settings for the node editor. The node editor is used for materials, textures and compositing, each has there own list of nodes that can be used.

The option for which nodes to display is shown in the header [image]